# Why dont both names appear when if the inp1 value is "d"?

Tags: javascript

I want both names to appear in the main element, but only the last name of the array appears.

```
  let arr = [
    {
      name: "dave"
    },
    {
      name: "david"
    }
  ];

  inp1.oninput = function(){
    console.log(inp1.value)
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i].name.includes(inp1.value)) {
        main.innerHTML = `
        <p>${arr[i].name}</p>
        `
        console.log(arr[i].name)
      }
    }
  }
```

in the console.log both names appear though, just not in the DOM

Comment: What do you think the `=` operator does? ;)

Comment: Well, it makes a p-tag with arr[i] once, but i would thin it would make a p-tag for both iterations of the loop?

Comment: @Mr.Ulis it does, but every time, you overwrite the previous one. If you want to add content without removing the previous one, you can use `+=` (equivalent of `x = x + 'foo'`)

Comment: Not quite, it sets the text to be dave, then it sets the text to be david (as in, overwrites). You need to join the strings together.

Comment: ah ok, with for instance .join() ?

Comment: @Mr.Ulis I think you got my point in the end, with the other comments, but `=` has nothing to do with "making a p-tag". It assigns a value to a variable, or (as here) an object property. I was trying to get you to realise that assigning more than once does exactly the same thing as assigning just once, with the last value you assigned.